# How to remove extra windows buttons from Firefox tab bar in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, firefox

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I had Firefox version 82.0.3 (64-bit) updated today. After the update, I have two sets of windows buttons (shown in the picture).

[image: image showing two sets of windows buttons, one encircled]

I want to remove the button set on the tab bar (encircled red). I don't know how to remove those. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the [Unite GNOME Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/). You should use the system title bar in Firefox with it.

To enable the system title bar in Firefox click the hamburger button <kbd>≡</kbd> on the top right → *Customize* → check *Title Bar* at the bottom left.

According to [this Unite issue](https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell/issues/201), you should restart Firefox after enabling the system title bar for Unite to work properly with it.